# Generate Code (java, python, etc.) from CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Is there a mechanism/framework available to generate code from a CloudFormation template?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You want to generate a CloudFormation template with code? The other way around?

Comment: 'generate code from CloudFormation template'.  I want to start with a template, and then generate the code (java, python, etc.) that would create that template.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk and https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/cdk-dasm/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tools:

- [Troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) is a Python library to create CloudFormation stacks from Python code.
- [CDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk) is a JavaScript library to create CloudFormation stacks from JavaScript / TypeScript code.